# How to add percents next to a column value

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a large dataframe but this is a small subsample of it. I am trying to add a percent
of each value right next to the daily value of each of my columns but in this case for only column 'F'.
I am able to create two extra columns of the percents and daily values together surrounded by curly brackets
but I was wondering if it is possible to get rid of the newly 'Perc_F' and 'both' columns and make the computations
within the 'F' column. Let me know if is not clear what I am trying to achieve.

```
library(tidyverse)

  SampleDate year F W  S LF
1 2013-01-05 2013 0 2  4  1
2 2013-01-06 2013 1 0  0  0
3 2013-01-07 2013 5 1  2  5
4 2013-01-08 2013 2 0  0  1
5 2013-01-09 2013 0 6  1  4
6 2013-01-10 2013 1 0  7  0
7 2013-01-11 2013 0 1  0  2
8 2013-01-12 2013 7 4 11  1

#Data
a <- structure(list(SampleDate = structure(c(15710, 15711, 15712, 
15713, 15714, 15715, 15716, 15717), class = "Date"), year = c("2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013"), F = c(0, 
1, 5, 2, 0, 1, 0, 7), W = c(2, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 1, 4), S = c(4, 
0, 2, 0, 1, 7, 0, 11), LF = c(1, 0, 5, 1, 4, 0, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
8L), class = "data.frame")
a$SampleDate <- as.Date(a$SampleDate)

#Create columns 'Perc_F' and 'both'with percents and values and percents respectively 
a %>% 
    mutate(Perc_F = F/sum(F),Perc_F = scales::percent(Perc_F)) |>
    mutate(both = paste0(F,"(",Perc_F,")"))
    
   SampleDate year F W  S LF Perc_F     both
1 2013-01-05 2013 0 2  4  1   0.0%  0(0.0%)
2 2013-01-06 2013 1 0  0  0   6.2%  1(6.2%)
3 2013-01-07 2013 5 1  2  5  31.2% 5(31.2%)
4 2013-01-08 2013 2 0  0  1  12.5% 2(12.5%)
5 2013-01-09 2013 0 6  1  4   0.0%  0(0.0%)
6 2013-01-10 2013 1 0  7  0   6.2%  1(6.2%)
7 2013-01-11 2013 0 1  0  2   0.0%  0(0.0%)
8 2013-01-12 2013 7 4 11  1  43.8% 7(43.8%)

#Instead of creating 'Perc_F' and 'both' columns, I would like
#The percents with curly brackets added to each value of the "F" column.
  
#Final dataframe should look like this for column "F"    
  SampleDate year F           W  S LF 
1 2013-01-05 2013 0(0.0%)     2  4  1   
2 2013-01-06 2013 1(6.2%)     0  0  0   
3 2013-01-07 2013 5(31.2%)    1  2  5  
4 2013-01-08 2013 2(12.5%)    0  0  1  
5 2013-01-09 2013 0(0.0%)     6  1  4   
6 2013-01-10 2013 1(6.2%)     0  7  0   
7 2013-01-11 2013 0(0.0%)     1  0  2   
8 2013-01-12 2013 7(43.8%)    4 11  1
```

Comment: Perhaps add `|> mutate(F = both) |> select(-Perc_F:both)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a function like this:

```r
add_percent <-
  function(x)
    paste0(x, "(", round(x / sum(x) * 100, 1), "%)")
```

And then apply it to the columns you want to add percent to.

```r
library(tidyverse)

a |>
  mutate(across(F:LF, add_percent))
#>   SampleDate year        F        W       S       LF
#> 1 2013-01-05 2013    0(0%) 2(14.3%)  4(16%)  1(7.1%)
#> 2 2013-01-06 2013  1(6.2%)    0(0%)   0(0%)    0(0%)
#> 3 2013-01-07 2013 5(31.2%)  1(7.1%)   2(8%) 5(35.7%)
#> 4 2013-01-08 2013 2(12.5%)    0(0%)   0(0%)  1(7.1%)
#> 5 2013-01-09 2013    0(0%) 6(42.9%)   1(4%) 4(28.6%)
#> 6 2013-01-10 2013  1(6.2%)    0(0%)  7(28%)    0(0%)
#> 7 2013-01-11 2013    0(0%)  1(7.1%)   0(0%) 2(14.3%)
#> 8 2013-01-12 2013 7(43.8%) 4(28.6%) 11(44%)  1(7.1%)
```

The problem with this strategy is that you’ll end up with
columns that are not useful for any further calculations.
If you are aiming to create result tables, you’d be better off using
a package for result tables, like `gt`, which has functions
to merge n and percent in the fashion you are looking for, and you’ll end
up with a table that looks great for publication/sharing.

```r
library(gt)

a |>
  mutate(across(F:LF, \(x) x / sum(x), .names = "perc_{.col}")) |>
  gt() |>
  fmt_percent(perc_F:perc_LF) |>
  cols_merge_n_pct(F, perc_F) |>
  cols_merge_n_pct(W, perc_W) |>
  cols_merge_n_pct(S, perc_S) |>
  cols_merge_n_pct(LF, perc_LF)
```

[image]

Comment: Great!!! Thank you @Till. Both approaches work for what I am trying to do.